# What event is fired on the child when a ViewStack's selectedChild is changed?

Tags: apache-flex, events

I have a `ViewStack` which uses the `selectedChild` property to change the view that is on top. I want to child to handle that event (for updating data that is inside the view).

According to the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/containers/ViewStack.html):

> ... When a different child container is selected, it seems to replace the old one because it appears in the same location. However, the old child container still exists; it is just invisible.

the view is "just invisible", so I though I should use the `show` event on the child to catch that, but that doesn't seem to work. Is that the right event, and am I doing something else wrong, or is there another event I should use?

The event is attached in the MXML file:

```
<mx:ViewStack>
  ...
  <mx:AdvancedDataGrid show="myListener(event)">
  </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
  ...
</mx:ViewStack>
```

Comment: have you tried `ADDED_TO_STAGE`?

Comment: Also it does seem like `FlexEvent.SHOW` is the right event looking at the ViewStack class, how are attaching your event listener?

Comment: @CyanAngel I updated my question (and also saw my mistake: the `show` was attached to a component inside the `View`, instead of the `View` itself.)

Comment: By "saw your mistake" does that mean the issue has been corrected, or does it persist?

Comment: @CyanAngel it is fixed, see my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

While updating my question, I saw my mistake. I attached the event to a compenent inside the container that was part of the `ViewStack`.

Putting the event on the container fixed it:

```
<mx:ViewStack>
  <mx:Canvas  show="myListener(event)">
    <mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
    </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
  </mx:Canvas>
</mx:ViewStack>
```